# How to toggle table TR element with another TR using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I m using Jquery to toggle tr elements in a table. The catch is I m trying to trigger the toggle using a button in another TR of the same table. However, it doesn't seem to toggle at all.

It works perfectly fine if I trigger it outside the table.

Here's the code so far..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".flip").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".flippanel").slideUp();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="flip">Flip it!</tr>
<br>
<tr class="flippanel">This is a paragraph with little content.</tr>
<br>
<tr class="flippanel">This is another small paragraph.</tr>
```

[A demo of the same to play around in JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9m6018zg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues here. Firstly your HTML is malformed. You're missing the `<td>` around the content within the `tr` - assuming those `tr` themselves are wrapped in `table`/`tbody` elements which are also missing in the question - and you cannot place `<br />` tags between `td`.

Secondly, jQuery animations are not well supported on `display: table-row` and other table level elements. To make them work you can make them `display: block` before performing the animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".flip").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".flippanel").css('display', 'block').slideUp();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="flip">
      <td>Flip it!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="flippanel">
      <td>This is a paragraph with little content.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="flippanel">
      <td>This is another small paragraph.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The caveat here is that there may be a slight jump in the element as its dimensions/padding/margin changes with the update to the `display` setting.

As such I would strongly suggest that if you need this animation to occur you avoid using tables for the layout.